# Python, Pyramid, Chameleon : parse Chameleon template in string

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon

I have a Chameleon template stored as a string. I've got it in this form, because I need to do my own processing first. Following that, I want to parse the template, possibly using 'render to response':

```
render_to_response('templates/foo.pt',
        {'foo':1, 'bar':2},
        request=request)
```

However, I can't figure out how to parse a template stored in a string, rather than pointing to one in a file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I can't figure out how to parse a template stored in a
>   string, rather than pointing to one in a file. Is this possible?

It seems so, according to the [api documentation](http://chameleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library.html#template-classes):

```
from chameleon import PageTemplate

t = PageTemplate('some string template')
rendered_content = t.render(encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks Burhan! That's what I was looking for. I've made a slight change to your answer, adding the required 'request' argument.

Comment: Are you sure about `request`? It could be that you need to pass the variables that are in the template, so its not just the actual HTTP request. In the snippet I posted there are no variables to interpolate, hence no other arguments to `render`. If you had `Say hello ${foo}` then you would pass in the substitution for `foo` to `render(encoding='utf-8',foo='bar')`.

Comment: When working with templates in the context of my question (Pyramid), passing the request was necessary.